# What is the difference between "посмотри" and "смотри"

Tags: разница

I have read somewhere that `смотри` is an unfinished action while `посмотри` is a completed action.

That does not help when I'm thinking of usage scenarios. For example I was watching the movie **Лёд** and there was a scene where the small girl tells her mother "`Смотри!`", which I understood to mean "`Look!`". So how do you classify that as either complete or incomplete when it hasn't even started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say that "смотри" is used for immediate action. E.g. when something funny is happening. And "посмотри" is used for a future action. E.g. when you recommend a movie, or ask to take a look at some document. Something like that.

Note that you can say "посмотри" for an immediate action, and in most cases it would sound ok. But saying "смотри" for a future action sounds weird and would probably be understood as "Look at it now"

Comment: I agree more with this answer. "Смотри вокруг" and  "Посмотри вокруг" have completely different meaning, it's not about being more calm and/or polite.

Comment: Maybe in context of something peculiar happening around, "посмотри" would be a bit more calm (e.g. "смотри что творится!" vs "посмотри что творится!"), but not in general, and I really don't think it has anything to do with politeness.

Comment: _Смотри_ can well be used for future, e.g. _Смотрите в следующем месяце на нашем канале_ in a TV ad. Or _Завтра выходной, смотри свои сериалы сколько влезет, а сегодня надо поработать._

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, "смотри" means the unfinished action, but not necessary the action that's going to happen right now.

Some of the meanings, prevailingly colloquial and possibly requiring certain intonation and (or) words:
- "смотри!.." with intonation raising and lowering, /и/ drawn out: "just you wait; watch yourself", with mildly confrontational/threatening connotation;
- "ты смотри" or "смотри ты" -- "what a surprise; would you look at that"; 
- "смотри там" -- "be careful/watchful (there); be on the watch (there)".

Your example means, almost literally: "Turn your eyes there (and see something)".

Now, "посмотри" means the action with a definite end/result to it:
- "посмотри в книге/Гугле" -- "look it up in the book/Google";
- "посмотри за ребенком" -- "watch the baby (for the period of time)".

Answer (score 2):

**Смотри** is a call for immediate action. **Посмотри** is more calm and polite:

- Смотри! = Look!
- Посмотри мою статью = Have a look at my article.

The Russian imperative is quite complex when it comes to aspect. All nuances would be impossible to list in a short post.

- [MasterRussian article](http://russianlearn.com/grammar/category/the_imperative_mood) (see "Usage of the Imperative" halfway down the page)
- [Timothy W. Grinsell. Russian Imperfective Imperatives](http://mitwpl.mit.edu/open/sub16/Grinsell.pdf)
- [Imperfective or perfective aspect for imperative](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/7329/2104) (related SO question)

In Russian:

- [2.4 Вид (rusgram.ru)](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#24)
- [Помета §18 в "Грамматическом словаре" А. А. Зализняка.](http://gramdict.ru/conjugation/symbols#para18)

Answer (score 1):

**Смотри** из typically about attracting attention to something *speaking for itself*, while **посмотри** is more about having a look at smth. and making (more or less deep) conclusions from that (approximately, *look* vs *have a look*).